# Reading data from local file to javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, text

I have a quiz app which displays the multiple choice questions. Currently, all my questions are hard coded in the array called questions[] in my game.js file. I want to modify my game.js file in such a way that all the questions and their choices and answer are read from either text, csv or excel file from the same root folder where game.js file exists.

The text file will contain following data:

---

question,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,answer

What is your name?,Ali,Noman,Ahmed,Dan,Noman

What is your favorite subject?,Math,Physics,Computer,English,Computer

What is 2 plus 2?Five,Six,Seven,Four,Four

---

And My game.js file is as follows:

```js
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));

let currentQuestion = {};

let acceptingAnswers = false;

let score = 0;

let questionCounter = 0;

let availableQuesions = [];

let questions = [{
        question: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript??",
        choice1: "<script>",
        choice2: "<javascript>",
        choice3: "<js>",
        choice4: "<scripting>",
        answer: 1
    },
    {
        question: "What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
        choice1: "<script href='xxx.js'>",
        choice2: "<script name='xxx.js'>",
        choice3: "<script src='xxx.js'>",
        choice4: "<script file='xxx.js'>",
        answer: 3
    },
    {
        question: " How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
        choice1: "msgBox('Hello World');",
        choice2: "alertBox('Hello World');",
        choice3: "msg('Hello World');",
        choice4: "alert('Hello World');",
        answer: 4
    }
];

const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;

const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;

startGame = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuesions = [...questions];
    console.log(availableQuesions);
    getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        return window.location.assign("/end.html");
    }

    questionCounter++;

    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);

    currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];

    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

    choices.forEach(choice => {
        const number = choice.dataset["number"];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
    });
    availableQuesions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
    console.log(availableQuesions);

    acceptingAnswers = true;
};

startGame();

choices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

        acceptingAnswers = false;
        const selectedChoice = e.target;
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];
        console.log(selectedAnswer);
        getNewQuestion();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can break this problem down into: 1) Reading a file 2) Parsing the CSV file into an array etc.

Comment: You also need to mention the platform you are using. Is this for Node.js?

Comment: Its not a node.js application. It is written in pure javascript, html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read the file. I suggest you use a JSON file to store the data, that will be much easier to work on.